# How do i use Visual Studio 2013 Pre-Build event to exclude a script from build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, build

I would like to know how to specify a pre build event that will exclude a script from a class library project build.

The info in the Microsoft website is lacking actual examples of this.

i have a script named _2DRadar.cs hich I need excluded from the  build
[image]

Comment: Then why do you want it in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a post-build event.  (and since that's **post**-build, it wouldn't make any sense)

Just set the Build Action to None.